# Calculate ticks for animation delay

Tags: xna, animation, sprites

Hi guys I am trying to calculate the correct elapsedTime for each frame in my animation.

Example I have a sprite called stance that has 20 frames I want to give each frame a tick delay property that determines how long that frame will last until next frame.

the question is how do I use the gameTime.elapsedTime to calculate the current elapsedTicks say for example the first frame has 20 ticks then

currentElapsedTicks += gameTime.ElapsedTime.Ticks?

Answer (score 1):

Add a timer to keep track of your elapsed time.  Take a look at the following:

```
float Timer;
const float FRAMES_PER_SECOND = 20;
const float TIMER = 1 / FRAMES_PER_SECOND;

void Init()
{
    Timer = TIMER;
}

public void Update(GameTime gametime)
{
    float elapsed = (float)gametime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    Timer -= elapsed;

    if (Timer <= 0)
    {
        ActiveFrame = NextFrame();
        Timer = TIMER;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed this stuff in [love-2d](https://love2d.org/): Here how i've done

```
anim.started=false
anim.curFrame=0
anim.accum = 0

function anim:update(dt)
    if anim.started then
        anim.accum = anim.accum+dt          
        if anim.accum > anim.frameTime then
            anim.accum = anim.accum-anim.frameTime
            if anim.aType=="loop"then
                anim.curFrame=(anim.curFrame+1)%anim.nFrames                
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This is lua code , you cane consider it as pseudo code. "anim" is a kind of "class" the stores "pointers" to each animation frame. `anim.curFrame` is the "pointer" at the frame currently rendered.

The idea is to accumulate delta time in `anim.accum` until `anim.accum` become grater than `anim.frameTime`.